# mongodb find in nested array or list

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list, queue

Why i not getting an answer to this find command?

```
db.test01.find( { Data: { $gte: 95 } }, {"Data.$": 1} );
```

test/example-data:

```
"Data" : {
    "a" : [  NumberLong(524288),  NumberLong(154981),  NumberLong(99) ],
    "b" : [  NumberLong(524288),  NumberLong(54i341),  NumberLong(32) ],
    "c" : [  NumberLong(524288),  NumberLong(159212),  NumberLong(96) ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for all documents where the third (last) number in the array is greater than 95.

Comment: for this scenario what are you expecting? (is "a" "c" the right answer?)